# Generator function not called when using Firebase listner

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, redux, redux-saga

I am using Firebase and Redux saga, and want to attache generator on firebase's listener as below.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref(`path`)
ref.on('value',function* (snapshot){

    yield put({ type: 'SOME_ACTION' })
```

When I run this program, callback function is not called. If I remove the *, it will be called.
Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saga effects don't work in all generators. Only in those run using `sagaMiddleware.runSaga()` or using effects such as `call`, `fork`, `spawn` etc.

One way to solve your problem is by using event channel, see https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/advanced/Channels.html#using-the-eventchannel-factory-to-connect-to-external-events